# Javascript setInterval not running in Safari on windows, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, safari, setinterval

So i am getting to know Canvas element and i made simple Canvas based gallery to get me started.
I use setInterval to update src of my Image and than onLoad to draw it in canvas. Problem is that it works in Chrome but not in Safari or IE.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400";
img.onload = function() {
    console.log('new image time');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
setInterval(function(){
    img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400";
}, 4000);`
```

I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lukaMis/T92TW/3/

So why doesn't setInterval run in Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So

I found out it was catching of the browser problem. Browser catche request for img.src and it did not work. If if append timestamp to request it works:

```
_time = Date.now();
img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400" + "?" + _time;
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T92TW/5

Luka

Comment: it seems safari does cache the page even if the content is different. Adding different parameter each request works